# Using a supercap to charge a MLCC

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor

Is is possible to use a 4V supercap (say ESR = 100 Ohm), to charge an X5R ceramic capacitor (assume also 4V)?

I think this is possible, so my second question: is there a way to calculate/estimate how long it will take to charge the MLCC?

Comment: The short answer is yes. The real answer depends on the parameters of the MLCC. The real question is why?

Answer (score 1):

t=RC tells you when the MLCC is 63% charged.

at t>10*RC the capacitor is practically fully charged (0.1%).

R=100, only you know C and the accuracy you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The MLCC will have negligible ESR (milliohms) compared to the supercapacitor, so the circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzHz8A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can calculate the total capacitance as Cx = 1/(1/C1 + 1/C2) or simply observe that Cx ~= C2 so the voltage of C1 won't change much from charging C2- it acts like a battery with 100 ohms in series. So we're left with a simple RC circuit, which is easy to deal with.

It will charge to within 0.1% of the final voltage in about 700usec in this case (7 time constants).